# UTC time is being rendered different

Tags: highcharts

I have two highChart and I do not know why the time is being rendered in different way. In the fist one 1483336800000-1483338600000 which is 07:00-07:30 is being rendered as 06:00-06:30 which is ok because the UTC time 
but in the second HighChart  1491885000000-1491890400000 which is  06:30-08:00 is being rendered with two hours in delay also 04:30-06:00. In the second case the time should be rendered with one hour in delay  as in the first case 
also from 05:30-07:00. What is the different between the two highCharts?

Here the first case:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zw7gq82/6/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',

{
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true,
        height: 192,
        spacingLeft: 30
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null,
        style: {
            "fontSize": "6px"
        }
    },
    subTitle: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 30,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: '#3366cc'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1,
        categories: ['', ''],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: 90
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                "fontSize": "6px",
                "color": "#000000"
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1800000,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    series: [{
        data: [ {
            x: 1,
            low: 1483336800000,
            high: 1483338600000,
            color: '#3366cc'
        } ]
    }]
}

);
```

The the second case:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zw7gq82/7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',

 {
     chart: {
         type: 'columnrange',
         inverted: true,
         height: 192,
         spacingLeft: 30
     },
     credits: {
         enabled: false
     },
     title: {
         text: null,
         style: {
             "fontSize": "6px"
         }
     },
     subTitle: {
         text: null
     },
     legend: {
         enabled: false,
     },
     plotOptions: {
         series: {
             pointWidth: 30,
             borderWidth: 0,
             borderColor: '#3366cc'
         }
     },
     xAxis: {
         min: 1,
         max: 1,
         categories: ['', ''],
         title: {
             text: null
         },
         labels: {
             rotation: 90
         },
         gridLineWidth: 0
     },
     yAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         title: {
             text: null
         },
         labels: {
             rotation: -45,
             style: {
                 "fontSize": "6px",
                 "color": "#000000"
             }
         },
         tickInterval: 1800000,
         gridLineWidth: 1
     },
     series: [{
         data: [{
             x: 1,
             low: 1491885000000,
             high: 1491890400000,
             color: '#3366cc'
         }

         ]
     }]
 }

 );
```

I just want to mention that I can not use this option in my case

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});
```

Comment: new Date(1483336800000) gives me Mon Jan 02 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time), so both of them are 2 hours off

Comment: @LiviuBoboia: I have used this page to check the time: http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.WO3Hh4jyhhG  1483336800000 --> Mon Jan 02 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0100

Comment: One is in January and the other in April.  Sounds like the difference is due to daylight savings time / summer time.

Comment: `new Date(1491885000000).toUTCString()` shows that your chart is correctly displaying the UTC time as 04:30.

Comment: @Joe: I think as you mentioned before it is due the  winter/summer time change.